# What is the equivalent server side component to TIdBlockCipherIntercept?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

I want to encrypt some packets sent between a `TIdTCPClient` and a `TIdTCPServer` component. On the client side, I can use `TIdBlockCipherIntercept` to implement my encryption/decryption. But, I can't find the matching *server side* component to assign to my `IdTCPServer`, and I couldn't find anything on Google. What should I do?

Comment: Isn't it just the same component? You say it can encrypt and decrypt on the client; why can't it also do both on the server?

Comment: No. :-( `TIdTCPServer.Intercept` is of `TIdServerIntercept` type, while `TIdTCPClient.Intercept` is of `TIdConnectionIntercept` type. And, despite the fact that there are two separate intercept components for compression, it seems like they forgot to include a server intercept for cipher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of a `TIdServerIntercept` descendant, you can handle the `OnConnect` event and assign a `TIdBlockCipherIntercept` instance to the server connection's `Intercept` property.

```
AContext.Connection.Intercept := TIdBlockCipherIntercept.Create(AContext.Connection);
```

Comment: This is what you have to do for now. I will look into getting a server-side component added soon.

Comment: Thanks, @Remy. My answer is based on [a post you made to the newsgroups](http://borland.public.delphi.internet.winsock.narkive.com/o9bNb3ch/tidblockcipherintercept-indy10) almost six years ago.

Comment: `TIdServerBlockCipherIntercept` has now been added (though I don't have a Component Palette icon made up for it yet).